# Group a query by every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query :

```
select

(select Sum(Stores) from XYZ where Year = '2013' and Month = '8' )
-
(select Sum(SalesStores) from ABC where Year = '2013' and Month = '8') as difference
```

Here in the above query Year and Month are also columns of a table.

I would like to know if there is a way to run the same query so that , it is run against every month of the year ?

Comment: create a custom view with 12 months in that and do a Cartesian join to the year and that should give you 12 months for each year.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to create a view

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH Months(Month) AS
(
    SELECT 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Month + 1
    FROM Months
    where Month < 12
)


SELECT '2013' [Year], m.Month, COALESCE(SUM(Stores), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(SalesStores), 0) [Difference]
FROM months m
LEFT JOIN XYZ x ON m.Month = x.Month
LEFT JOIN ABC a ON a.Month = m.Month

GROUP BY m.Month
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but you shouldn't be using an `inner join` in the case that some month there is data on only one table

Comment: A `JOIN` **is** an `INNER JOIN`. You should use `FULL JOIN` and have a logic with `ISNULL` for the `SELECT`

Comment: @Lamak - The OP asked for a query that runs against every month of the year. Either or both tables may be missing some months. A numbers table or other source of months is needed to ensure results for _every_ month.

Comment: Here is a cleaner solution using CTE

Answer (score 2):

If there are months without data/rows within `XYZ` or `ABC` tables then I would use `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(x.[Month], y.[Month]) AS [Month],
       ISNULL(x.Sum_Stores, 0) - ISNULL(y.Sum_SalesStores, 0) AS Difference
FROM   
(
    SELECT [Month], Sum(Stores) AS Sum_Stores 
    FROM   XYZ 
    WHERE  [Year] = '2013' 
    GROUP BY [Month]
) AS x
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Month], Sum(SalesStores) AS Sum_SalesStores 
    FROM   ABC 
    WHERE  [Year] = '2013' 
    GROUP BY [Month]
) AS y ON x.[Month] = y.[Month]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GROUP BY` in your inner trades, and then run a join, like this:

```
SELECT left.Month, (left.sum - COALESCE(right.sum, 0)) as difference
FROM (
    SELECT Month, SUM(Stores) as sum
    FROM XYZ WHERE Year = '2013'
    GROUP BY Month
) left
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT Month, SUM(Stores) as sum
    FROM ABC WHERE Year = '2013'
    GROUP BY Month
) right ON left.Month = right.Months
```

Note the use of `COALESCE`. It lets you preserve the value of the first `SUM` in case when there are no records for the month in the `ABC` table.

Comment: Same as the comment above, you shouldn't be using an `INNER JOIN`, but a `FULL JOIN` instead. anyway, +1

Comment: @Lamak You're right, it's a good idea to add an outer join there. I also added `COALESCE` to avoid seeing `NULL` when there's no matching month in `ABC`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the following example uses the UNION ALL operator with CTE

```
;WITH cte AS
 (SELECT SUM(Stores) AS Stores, [Month]
  FROM dbo.XYZ
  WHERE [Year] = '2013'
  GROUP BY [Month]      
  UNION ALL
  SELECT -1.00 * SUM(SalesStores), [Month]
  FROM dbo.ABC      
  WHERE [Year] = '2013'
  GROUP BY [Month]
  )
  SELECT [Month], SUM(Stores) AS Difference
  FROM cte  
  GROUP BY [Month]
```

Demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6420c/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
  ;WITH Months(Month) AS
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Month + 1
        FROM Months
        where Month < 12
    )

    SELECT Months. Month ,
(select isnull(Sum(Stores),0) from XYZ where Year = '2013' and Month = Months.Month) - (select isnull(Sum(SalesStores),0) from ABC where Year = '2013' and Month =Months.Month) as difference
    FROM Months
```